No qualifying bean after migrating to spring 6.1
after migrating to Spring 6.1.11
public interface IInterface {}
 
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "condition", havingValue = "A", matchIfMissing = true)
@Component
public class A implements IInterface {}


@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "condition", havingValue = "B")
@Component
public class B implements IInterface {}

getting error:
No qualifying bean of type 'com.IInterface' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: A,iInterface
Why it conisders interface as matching bean?! how to solve it?
